# Setar o valor do input cujo o name tem colchetes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Conforme descrito no titulo, segue o exemplo abaixo:

---- HTML

```
<form id="nameGenderForm">
<table id="teste">
     <tr>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th >Gender</th>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td id="11"><input type="hidden" name="11" value=""></td>
            <td  id="12"><input type="hidden" name="12" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td  id="21"><input type="hidden" name="[21].value"  value=""></td>
            <td  id="22"><input type="hidden" name="[22].value"  value=""></td>
        </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---- SCRIPT

```
$("#nameGenderForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   $("input[name=11]").val("AAAA")
    $("input[name=22]").val("BBBB")


   //$("input[name=[21].value]").val("FFFF")  // aqui: como setar nesse caso?
   //$("input[name=[22].value]").val("ZZZZZ")

    rawData = $('#teste input:hidden').serializeArray();
    var formData = JSON.stringify(rawData);

     alert(formData);

});
```

Para facilitar, coloquei no JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/leandrotss/jf5dg98o/4/

Comment: Qual sua intenção em usar os colchetes ?

Comment: Não sei pq mas parcial view montou a tabela ssim. Talvez pq em vez de usar ienumerable ou uso o ilist.

Comment: SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608487/how-do-i-reference-an-element-by-name-with-brackets-in-it

Comment: ienumerable ? ilist?  isso seria algo com C# ?

Comment: Sim. Só preciso descobrir como setar/buscar o esse elemento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer dessa forma:

```
$('input[name="[21].value"]').val("AAAA");
```

Fiddle com exemplo:

> https://jsfiddle.net/e0r4LmnL/

Answer (score 1):

Existe um *seletor css* para isso:

```
$('[name*="["]').val("novo valor");
```

Vai procurar quem contem em qualquer lugar do atributo *name* um colchete `[`.

[w3schools exemplo.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)